# using Oracle Loader to import HBase data into Oracle table

Tags: mysql, oracle, hadoop, nosql, hbase

I have **data in HBase table that I am trying to import into an Oracle or a MySQL table**. I heard there is an Oracle Loader that can server the purpose.

Anyone tried to import Hadoop HBase data into an Oracle table? If so, could you please give me a reference link on how I can do that?

Comment: I have tried Sqoop to do the same but was not successful

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Error manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sqlException: Unknown initial character set index ‘224’ received from server.

Error tool.ExportTool: Encounteres IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate fro ClassWriter

Comment: I tried to sqoop export hbase table to oracle/mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you are doing this. Last time I had checked there was no support for **export from HBase to SQL DBs through Sqoop**. You are facing this issue because of this fact. You could probably try :

- Exporting HBase data to HDFS and then export it to Oracle.
- Mapping HBase tables to Hive and do the export.

I'm also not very sure if Oracle data loader supports HBase exports. Could you please share the link where you have read about this?

**Edit :**

If you are facing issues with other tools, you could probably make use of **[DBOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBOutputFormat.html)**.

Comment: I have heard about Oracle Loader as a viable option from a friend. I tried to google but couldn't find any documentation on it and hence I posted in SOF.

Comment: Have you ever tried Toad for Cloud database - http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/nosql/w/wiki/355.hbase.aspx?

Comment: I see. I haven't seen it either. No, I haven't tried Toad. Frankly speaking I never had to export anything from HBase into any RDBMS.

Comment: I tried to export HBase table to HDFS (http://www.sethcall.com/blog/2010/04/10/how-to-export-and-import-an-hbase-table/) but I have an error while running the export "Encounterest problems when prefetch META table, Cannot find row in .META for table /var/hbase/hbase-data-dir/webpage,,99999999999"

Comment: I tried to see if there is any .META table in hbase shell, when I tried scan '.META', it says unknown table META. But when I scan 'webpage', it display rows and columns. Not sure what is this .META that Hbase to HDFs export is looking for

Comment: It is **.META.**. Mind the **dot(.)**. It is a table which is maintained by HBase to store the metadata of your tables.

Comment: Thanks so much, Tariq. Is that .META table is something I should create in hbase?

Comment: No. It's the duty of HBase to do that for you.

Comment: could you please tell me where to check if .META exists in hbase? I tried to scan '.META' in hbase, it says unknown table

Comment: It's **.META.** and not **.META**   You are missing the dot after META

Comment: Thanks Tariq!!! it successfully exported hbase to hdfs creating two files 'part-m-0000' and '_SUCCESS'. Could you please tell me which of these two should I use to export into Oracle?

Comment: part-m-0000. This is the file which actually holds the data.